# Build Qt (static linking) for Visual Studio 2017 32bits

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2017

On my Windows 7 SP1 machine I would like to use Qt in Visual Studio and compile Qt projects with Visual Studip with static linking,to be able to share my projects in a single .exe file.
Since there are no precompiled libraries for Visual Studio 2017 32bits (although they exists for x64),i'm going to compile Qt from sources.

Following Qt's documentation,I started by installing Python 2.7.13 and Active-Perl,and adding their installation path to the PATH variable,along with the gnuwin32/bin folder

Then i created a qt5vars.cmd file under C:\Qt,here's his content :

```
REM Set up \Microsoft Visual Studio 2017, where <arch> is \c amd64, \c x86, etc.
CALL "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x86
SET _ROOT=C:\Qt\5.9.1
SET PATH=%_ROOT%\qtbase\bin;%_ROOT%\gnuwin32\bin;%PATH%
REM Uncomment the below line when using a git checkout of the source repository
#REM SET PATH=%_ROOT%\qtrepotools\bin;%PATH%
SET _ROOT=
```

And finally I unzipped Qt sources (downloaded from [here](http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.9/5.9.1/single/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.9.1.zip) to C:\Qt\5.9.1,and jom under C:\Qt\jom

I'm planning to use these commands (after executing qt5vars.cmd) to compile and install Qt :

```
configure -debug-and-release -opensource -platform win32-msvc2017 -static -nomake examples -nomake tests -prefix C:\Qt-5.9.1
jom -j 2
jom install
```

I already installed Qt vs tools in VS2017.

Is the procedure correct,or should I change something ? (particularly in the configure command)

Comment: You definitely don't want to build a static debug version. Use dynamic linked framework for debugging.

Comment: Thank you,then i'll only use -release

Comment: A static debug build will take tremendous time and disk space. And it is not really needed, you only need static linking for production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks good. My only remarks would be:
To remove gnuwin32 path as I don't see a reason why would you need it.

And consider making a shadow build to keep Qt sources unpolluted.

```
set _SHADOW_DIR="C:\build_static"
set _SOURCE_DIR="C:\SrcQt5.9.1"
...
cd %_SHADOW_DIR%
call %_SOURCE_DIR%\configure ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice !

Answer (score 0):

Run: "x86 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2017"

Or from console

```
%comspec% /k "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars32.bat"
```

Go to your Qt source dir "qt-everywhere-src-5.14.0/"
Run

```
configure -static -debug-and-release -prefix "f:\Qt\Static\build\5.14\build" -platform win32-msvc -qt-zlib -qt-pcre -qt-libpng -qt-libjpeg -qt-freetype -opengl desktop -qt-sqlite -sql-odbc -no-openssl -opensource -confirm-license -make libs -nomake tools -nomake examples -nomake tests -skip qtwebengine
```

After some hours run

```
nmake
```

Wait some hours again and run

```
nmake install
```

A lot of post about qtwebengine,ssl i simply disable this. 
Hope this post help you save your expensive time.